# PHP page not saving form and parsing output

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this PHP page that grabs the response's from a form (well i hope it does) and then inputs the data into a table. I then echo the response from the table on the same page. Im using ajax on the form page to send over the form values and on success of the ajax call load the data into a div. this is all done without a refresh, however no information is being sent and it just refresh's the page

my php page -

```
<?php

$comment_name =  $_POST["name"];
$comment_body =  $_POST["comment"];
$film_no =  $_POST["hidden"];
echo $comment_name;
echo $comment_body;
echo $film_no; 


// Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "****") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("ignitet1_CheckFilm") or die(mysql_error()); 

$query1 = "INSERT INTO film_comments (comments_id,film_no,name,comment) 
VALUES ('','$film_no', '$comment_name','$comment_body')";
$runquery1 = mysql_query($query1)or die(mysql_error()); 


$getComments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM film_comments where film_no = '$film_no'") 
                 or die(mysql_error());     

                 while($info = mysql_fetch_array($getComments)) 
                 { 
                echo "<p>";
                echo $info['name']; 
                echo ":</p>";
                echo "<p>";
                echo $info['comment'];  
                echo "</p>";

                echo "<p>Comment posted on:";
                echo $info['timestamp'];    
                echo "</p>";
                echo "</div>";      
?>
```

my form and javascript code

```
<form id="ContactForm2" onsubmit="return submitForm()" >        
<div>                                               <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden" value="2">
<label for="name">Your Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<label for="body">Comment Body</label>                  
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="comment" class="button" value="Submit" />
<div class="form_result"> </div>
</form> </div>

<script>

function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'comment.php', data:$('#ContactForm2').serialize(), success: function(response) {
        $('#ContactForm2').find('.form_result').html(response);
    }});


}
```

Everything i try seems to not work. help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: output your $_POST in PHP and the result of $('#ContactForm2').serialize() so at least you know if you are sending right data and receiving it.

Comment: also your function probably need to be above the markup and "onsubmit="return submitForm()"" should be "onsubmit="submitForm()" as your function doesn't return anything anyway so you would return undefined (unless it's your way of cancelling default behaviour but that's not a nice way)

Comment: You have not closed your while loop.. is it mistake while u added php codes here?

Comment: FYI, you are **wide open** to SQL injection and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to do prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: how would i output the result of serialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with your php its working fine for me.

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sub').click(function(){
        $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'comment.php', data:$('#ContactForm2').serialize(), success: function(response) {
        $('#ContactForm2').find('.form_result').html(response);
    }});
    });
})

    </script>
    <body>
        <div>
        <form id="ContactForm2"> >                                                       <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden" value="2">
<label for="name">Your Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<label for="comment">Comment Body</label>                  
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="sub" class="button" value="Submit" />
<div class="form_result"> </div>
</form> </div>


    </body>
</html>
```